# Similar saying to 'lost his/her train of thought'

Tags: synonyms, british-english, figures-of-speech

Imagine someone reeling of a sentence, becoming distracted, and not being able to remember where they were in the previous sentence for a few seconds. I already know, 'lost their train of thought' but there is another similar saying, which I cannot remember.

It also being with "I lost my...." Its kind of an alternative.

Comment: I lost my place or my focus, or I had a senior moment or a brain fart.

Comment: "someone reeling"? You lost me.

Comment: I had a term in mind but I had a brain fart and forgot it!

Comment: I lost my thread?

Comment: Martin Scorsese would say you lost the "narrative thread".

Answer (score 1):

Lost track of what I was saying?
Forgot where I was going with that?